# Is there any way of getting sessions created + destroying sessions on TokBox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend, opentok, tokbox

I want to get a list of all those sessions that were created but were never used/consumed(before a certain period) and I want to destroy those unused sessions. (For clearing the unnecessary sessions created on the cloud.)

Is there any way to achieve both these tasks? (Getting sessions + Destroying sessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the [session monitoring API](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/) which sends you events to a specified webhook URL. Using the information sent to your server you can see if someone joins a session and cross reference that with the sessions you have created.

Sessions can not be [destroyed](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-session/), but the authentication for sessions can be.